# How can i fix this grid board to not to be overlapping the main details in my program?

Tags: python, pygame

This program will draw a grid board with main details (circles) inside it

[image: Screenshot]

## Issue

But the board is overlapping the main details which made the main details unlikely to be displayed on screen (see screenshot below)

## Pygame code

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((915,915))

## 0 = nâu // 1 = xanh da trời // 2 = xanh lá // 3 = xanh đậm // 4 = tím // 5 = vàng // 6 = đỏ
colors = [(102,51,0),(0,255,255),(0,255,0),(0,51,204),(102,0,204),(255,255,0),(255,0,0)]
slots = []
x = 0
y = 0
click_pos = (0,0)
play = True
#Size of squares
size = 83
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (200,200,200)
deep_gray = (20,20,20)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
boardLength = 9
i = 0
z = 0
clicked = False
selecting = False
ball_spawn = True
balls_x = []
balls_y = []
ball_amount = 0
ball_color = []
ball_drew = 0
get_ball_pos = True
click_once = 0
balls_per_generate = 3
balls_generated = 0
selected_ball_x = 0
selected_ball_y = 0
move = False
check_move = False

#bg color
gameDisplay.fill(deep_gray)                                           
while play == True:
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            click_pos = list(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            clicked = True
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False
    # GRID
    i = 0       
    z = 0
    while boardLength > z:
        #border
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [size-5,size-5,boardLength*size+5 ,boardLength*size+5])
        #grid squares
        for i in range(1,boardLength+1):
            for z in range(1,boardLength+1):
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, gray, [size*z,size*i,size-5,size-5])
    #get click pos on grid
    if clicked == True:
        click_once += 1
        if click_once == 1:
            x = round((click_pos[0]-size/2) / size)
            y = round((click_pos[1]-size/2) / size)
            if x > 0 and x < 10 and y > 0 and y < 10:
                grid_x = x*size
                grid_y = y*size
            clicked = False
            selecting = True
            get_ball_pos = True
            ball_spawn = True
            balls_per_generate += 0
    else:
        click_once = 0
    #selector
    if selecting:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, (grid_x,grid_y,size-5,size-5), 5)
        #get selected ball
        if x in balls_x and y in balls_y:
            selected_ball_x = balls_x.index(x)
            selected_ball_y = balls_y.index(y)   
            check_move = not check_move
        elif check_move == True:
            move = True
            selecting = False
            check_move = False
            balls_x[selected_ball_x]
            balls_y[selected_ball_y]
    # BALLS
    while ball_spawn:    
        while get_ball_pos:
            ball_grid_x = randint(1,9)
            ball_grid_y = randint(1,9)
            if not (ball_grid_x, ball_grid_y) in zip(balls_x, balls_y):      
                if ball_amount < balls_per_generate:         
                    balls_x.append(ball_grid_x)
                    balls_y.append(ball_grid_y)
                    ball_color.append(colors[randint(0,6)])               
                    balls_generated += 1
                    ball_amount += 1
                if balls_generated >= balls_per_generate:
                    get_ball_pos = False
        while ball_drew < ball_amount:
            pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, ball_color[ball_drew], (balls_x[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2, balls_y[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2), 25)
            pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, (balls_x[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2, balls_y[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2), 25, 5)
            ball_drew += 1
            #check LOSE
            if ball_drew == 81:
                play = False
                ball_spawn = False                 
        ball_drew = 0
        ball_spawn = False  
    #debugger    
    print(balls_x)
    #final result
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

it draws the grid board, then draw the main details on top of the grid board, then update the display, but the grid board is more likely to be on top of the main details.
how can i fix this?

Comment: What are the "main details"?

Comment: it is the circles drawn, it is supposed to be on top of the grid board, but the board is overlapping them @Rabbid76

Comment: No, the circle is not drawn. The circle is only drawn in a single frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redraw the entire scene (the grid and all the objects) in every frame:

```py
while play == True:
    
    # event loop
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            click_pos = list(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            clicked = True
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False

    # clear dispaly
    gameDisplay.fill(0)
    
    # draw grid
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [size-5,size-5,boardLength*size+5 ,boardLength*size+5])
    for i in range(1,boardLength+1):
        for z in range(1,boardLength+1):
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, gray, [size*z,size*i,size-5,size-5])

    # draw all the objects
    for x, y, c in zip(balls_x, balls_y, ball_color):
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, c, (x*size + size*0.5 - 2, y*size + size*0.5 - 2), 25)
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, (x*size + size*0.5 - 2, y*size + size*0.5 - 2), 25, 5)

    # [...]
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: Why do you not try my code? You only draw the circles when `ball_spawn` is `True`. However `ball_spawn`is only `True` for a single frame when you click somewhere. Decouple the game logic and the drawing of the scene. Separate your application loop into well-defined sections that include event handling, logic, and drawing.

Comment: Oh, really sorry about that @Rabbid76